Interpolation by central bank cometee meeting dates
I want to have an interpolation, to the yield curve,
In the term up to a year, the forward daily curves will be the same between central bank cometee meeting dates (to be precice, the implemantation dates)
did anyone have experience with such interpolation?
Thank you in advance.
Zeev

Do you have a specific question about interpolation, or are you just curious about people's experiences on QSE?
